# Zxing PDF417 edit padding / quiet zone

Tags: java, zxing

I am generating a PDF417 barcode with the zing library. All good with that...

```
writer = new PDF417Writer();
bitMatrix = writer.encode(barcodeMessage.getData(),
    BarcodeFormat.PDF_417, WIDTH, WIDTH / 2, // To maintain a width/height ratio
    ImmutableMap.of(
        EncodeHintType.PDF417_COMPACT, Boolean.TRUE,
        EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, messageEncoding
    )
);

barcodeBg = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bitMatrix);
```

But I was wondering if there is any way to be able to edit how much quiet zone is left at each side? Something similar to this... http://www.racoindustries.com/barcodegenerator/2d/pdf417.aspx that allows you to select how much space you have on each side.

I have tried adding this EncodeHintType.MARGIN but for this type of barcode it does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for EncodeHintType.MARGIN for PDF417 was added to zxing in the newest release 3.0.0.

Comment: You're right. I just tested it. Thank you!! By the way... by any chance do you know if the 3.0 release is already available through Maven?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. But in my opinion it should be available.